# Can't see database content on web browser, asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have been following this tutorial along https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-e554Zt3n4 [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-e554Zt3n4) to make a web application connected to a db. I replaced client with student. The issue that I have ran into is I cant see the database content on my browser[No data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5oxn.png) . I have followed the steps and added the system data sql, as well as created the database and populated it but the data wont show up. here is the page code [cshtml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mRCa.png) everything but the table body is showing up. other references include the database content [The data that wont show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFvNk.png) and the page cs code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace assignment2.Pages.Students
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<StudentInfo> listStudents = new List<StudentInfo>();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=unicafschooldb;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM students";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                           while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                StudentInfo studentInfo = new StudentInfo();
                                studentInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                                studentInfo.name =  reader.GetString(1);
                                studentInfo.email =  reader.GetString(2);
                                studentInfo.phone =  reader.GetString(3);
                                studentInfo.teacher =  reader.GetString(4);
                                studentInfo.course =  reader.GetString(5);

                                listStudents.Add(studentInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public class StudentInfo
    {
        public string id;
        public string name;
        public string phone;
        public string email;
        public string teacher;
        public string course;
    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong here? please help.

Comment: You didn't post any code that *displays* those students. Links to videos or images aren't code. `listStudents` is a field, not a property. There may not be anything to display anyway. Did you try debugging to see if the query returns anything?

Comment: Instead of videos I'd suggest following [the documentation tutorial first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to see what a Razor pages application really looks like.

Comment: I posted a link to the video for reference, I also posted the images to show that there is data in the database and finally I have posted the cs code above to display the code on the browser along with the cshtml code that has the table for the content.

Comment: Videos aren't code or reference. They can't be copied, compiled or tested. `System.Data.SqlClient` was replaced by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, so that video is obsolete to begin with

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database for example? The screenshot you posted isn't from SSMS. If you used Visual Studio's data tools you may have written data to a LocalDB instance instead of SQL Server Express. If `ExecuteReader` returns no results, there are no rows in that table

Comment: I added the video so the reader know what I am talking about. I have updated to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient though but the issue is still there. I also checked to see if the data is there in microsoft sql server and it is. would have posted the picture if I knew how to

Answer (score -1):

When you create the database connection, you can click the Test Connection button to check whether you can connect to the database correctly:
[image]

And in your code, You can set breakpoints to check the running status of the program, such as when connecting to the database, reading query results, and catching exceptions:
[image]
SQL Server Express LocalDB  is installed by default with Visual Studio, you can use it to set you database by SQL Server Object Explorer, Here is an example you can use as refer to:

My LocalDB  :

[image]

ConnectionString:

```
String connectionString = "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=unicafschooldb;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
```

I set some initial data:
[image]
Returned results:
[image]